# How do I show $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) d\mu(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) w(x)dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

i)Let $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathbb{R}$ with the density $w$ i.e $\mu(A)=\int_{A}w(x)dx$.

Prove that, using the definition of integral that for any measurable function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) d\mu(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) w(x) dx$.

ii) Let $F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow (0,\infty) $ be an increasing, differentiable function, and $\mu((a,b])=F(b)-F(a)$.Prove that for any measurable function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) d\mu(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) w(x) dx$.

I proved part i), by taking the measurable function as

1. Indicator function
2. Simple function
3. Non-negative function
4. Signed function
5. Complex valued function.

I prove every case except #3 Non-negative function case. Can anyone suggest some hint for this case and ii) part of the question?

Comment: maybe you mean $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) w(x)dx$? In this case this follows immediately from the definition of the integral of Lebesgue

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 3):

Once you have proved (2), (3) follows by Monotone Convergence Theorem. Recall that if $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is a non-negative measurable function, we can choose a sequence of simple function $(f_n)$ such that $0\leq f_1 \leq f_2 \leq \ldots \leq f$ and $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwisely.